# Magento 2: How to scan and delete all the system config values that start with some prefix

Tags: magento2.3, system-config, core-config-data

Required to delete all the possible values from `core_config_data` that are having path starts with "**Softtech**" via `Helper/CoreConfig.php` to call `Model/HandleConfig.php`

i.e.

- Softtech/settings/enable
- Softtech/settings/productpage
- Softtech/settings/categorypage
- Softtech/settings/cmspage
- Softtech/settings/cartpage

Comment: through database query ?

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: What would be the purpose of this? If your just resetting a module, I would use a database query. Is there a reason or use case to do this from php?

Comment: do not want to use direct sql query...this can be an array of fields and loop will trigger `deleteConfig` method of config model.

Comment: @MageSoftech, When you want to remove that all values from core_config_data table ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya controller -> helper or controller > helper > model